# setInterval works setTimeout doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor

I'm currently writing async specs for an Atom-package using APM 1.6.0, Node 0.10.40 and Jasmine 1.3. Unfortunately i can't get `setTimeout` working.

Since Jasmine 1.3 uses sequential [`runs`-blocks](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) to allow asynchronous testing, i tried to comprehend the example from the docs.

It turns out that the `setTimeout`-callback is never invoked.

While searching for the reason why this may happen, i renamed the `setTimeout`-statement to `setInterval` (as both functions have the same signature).

If i execute the following code

```js
describe('an asynchronous test', () => {
    it('should do some async stuff', () => {
        runs(() => {
            setInterval(() => {
                console.info('async');
            }, 75);

            setTimeout(() => {
                console.info('async2');
            }, 75);
        });
        waitsFor(() => {
            return false;
        }, 'missing events'); // will wait ~5 seconds.
    });
});
```

i get the following output:

```
async
async
async
...
```

Why is the `setInterval`-function working properly, while the `setTimeout` is entirely not working?

Edit: the first version of the question did not mention that the specs are run in the Atom-environment. Pardon.

Comment: [Works for me](http://output.jsbin.com/vemayur) (And also on Node)

Comment: `setTimeout` only executes once after 75ms. Is it possible you're just missing the output? It would be at the top of your console. Maybe try setting the time to a higher number?

Comment: Some testing frameworks require that you identify async tests in some way, are you sure you're doing that correctly for Jasmine?

Comment: I am pardon, i missed to add a reference to the Atom-environment. The whole test waits ~5s. I am surely not missing any events.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the test is not working, since the timeout is not being invoked. Jasmine 1.3 needs to fulfill a dependency which would be set in the waitsFor-statement.

Comment: @florianb: I figured it was that the test wasn't working. Fundamentally, of course, `setTimeout` works. Shouldn't you be setting a flag in the `setTimeout` that you return from `waitsFor` rather than always returning `false`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: thanks - but in that case waitsFor waits for ~5 seconds until timeout. I did that to wait for all log-events of the timer-functions. When i was implementing it like it was written down in the docs it did also kick the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution through this [Post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/solved-settimeout-not-working-firing-in-specs-tests/11427/16). It leads to the [spec-helper](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/spec/spec-helper.coffee#L70)-file where `setTimeout` is stubbed by a Jasmine-spy.

To make `setTimeout` work again it is necessary to remove the spy with `jasmine.unspy()`. After `setTimeout` has been invoked it is possible to reactivate the spy with `spyOn()`.

The following lines illustrate that with my example from above:

```js
runs(() => {
    // disable spy
    jasmine.unspy(window, 'setTimeout');

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.info('async2');
    }, 75);

    // reenable spy
    spyOn(window, 'setTimeout')
        .andCallFake(window.fakeSetTimeout);
});
```